# python google api getting specific information

Tags: python, api, search, unicode

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build


def main():
  service = build("customsearch", "v1",                          
  developerKey="<mykey>")

  res = service.cse().list(
  q='the.hobbit.2012', 
  cx='<the other key>',
 ).execute()
 pprint.pprint(res)
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Is the code i run and here is the result i get:

```
{u'context': {u'title': u'IMDB Search Engine'},
 u'items': [{u'cacheId': u'kzgitw0HPeAJ',
             u'displayLink': u'www.imdb.com',
             u'formattedUrl': u'www.imdb.com/title/tt0903624/',
             u'htmlFormattedUrl': u'www.imdb.com/title/tt0903624/',
             u'htmlSnippet': u'Directed by Peter Jackson. With Martin Freeman, Ian     McKellen, Richard Armitage<br>  , Andy Serkis. A younger and more reluctant <b>Hobbit</b>,     Bilbo Baggins, sets out on <b>...</b>',
             u'htmlTitle': u'<b>The Hobbit</b>: An Unexpected Journey (<b>2012</b>) -     IMDb',    
             u'kind': u'customsearch#result',
             u'link': u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903624/',
             u'pagemap': {u'aggregaterating': [{u'bestrating': u'10',
                                                u'ratingcount': u'157,307',
                                                u'ratingvalue': u'8.4',
                                                u'reviewcount': u'855'}],
```

Now my question is, if i wanted to get the information from u'formattedUrl'
i thought i could do

```
urlinfo = res['item']['url']['formattedUrl']
```

like i would have done it with forexample Objconfig. But that wont work. So how do i get  specific information out? Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[From Google API Client documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started?hl=en): "The response is a Python object built from the JSON response..."

The value of `items` is an array, so you need to specify the id of the element you want to retrieve:

```
urlinfo = res['items'][0]['formattedUrl']
```